# Function window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função no meu `form`
Porém eu não tenho um `button` `submit`, mas eu tenho um `button` que envia os dados, e ao clicar nele, ele aparece esta mensagem da function abaixo, como posso colocar um exception ? Ou algo do tipo, este button faz a função do submit, porém não é do `type="submit"`

```
  $(function () {
    var init_form = $('#model').serialize(); // Result example: "name=&email=&message=" // Cancel event onbeforeunload when Submit 
   $(':submit').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; }); window.onbeforeunload = function () { var check_form = $('#model').serialize(); if (check_form === init_form) return null; return 'Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?'; };
});
```

Comment: no lugar da mensagem quer que dispare um *exception* é isso?

Comment: Não, eu quero que neste button ele não seja disparado este exemplo, pois ele aparece como se fosse sair do formulário, só que na verdade ele está fazendo o submit.

Comment: Consegui resolver, acrescentei esta linha na function `$('#btn-enviar').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });`